# How do I check if my app is resumed by a Siri shortcut

Tags: ios, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am working with **Siri shortcuts**. I wanted to know if my app is launched from a Siri shortcut in the following cases:

1. When the application is running in the background
2. When the application is not running in the background

For **case 2**, I can use the "**didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**" method but for **case 1**, I am not sure what approach to use.

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this check in your `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        if userActivity.interaction?.intent is {YOUR_INTENT_CLASS} {
            // App launched via that particular shortcut.
        }
    }
}
```