# How do I check if my app is launched by a Siri shortcut on WatchOS?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos, sirikit

I am trying to create a custom SiriKit shortcut on WatchOS. I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142191/how-do-i-check-if-my-app-is-resumed-by-a-siri-shortcut) for an iOS problem, but I believe that the solution is different in watchOS.

In order to do this, I followed these steps:

1. In WatchKit Extension target, I added the Siri capability;
2. I've created an Intents Extension through: File> New > Target > watchOS > Intents Extension;
3. In the Intent Extension group, I created a SiriKit Intent Definition file. In this file, I made some custom changes and checked "Intent is eligible for Siri Suggestions" box;
4. In the Intent Extension group, I also created a file named HandWashIntentHandler.swift that has the following code:

```
class HandWashIntentHandler: NSObject, HandWashIntentHandling{
    func handle(intent: HandWashIntent, completion: @escaping (HandWashIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "HandWashIntent")
        let title = "Hand Wash"
        activity.title = title
        activity.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Start hand wash"
        activity.isEligibleForPrediction = true
        activity.persistentIdentifier = title

        let response = HandWashIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp,
                                              userActivity: activity)

        completion(response)
    }
}
```

5. Then, in IntentHandler.swift, I've added the following code:

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension {

    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        guard intent is HandWashIntent else {
             fatalError("Unhandled intent type: \(intent)")
        }

        return HandWashIntentHandler()
    }
}
```

6. Finally, in the Info.plist inside the Intent Extension Group, I've added "HandWashIntent" in the IntentsSupported. Similarly, in the Info.plist inside the WatchKit Extension Group, I've added "HandWashIntent" in the NSUserActivityTypes.

---

So, basically, I want the spoken shortcut "Start hand wash" through. This shortcut would open the application and push a specific controller. I read in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846415/whats-the-equivalent-of-app-delegate-file-for-apple-watch-app) that the WKExtensionDelegate in watchOS is "equivalent" to AppDelegate in iOS. Then, I've tried to manipulate the userActivity in ExtensionDelegate, but there is no function to do so.

Then, I used the function [handle(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/2798966-handle) in the ExtensionDelegate:

```
func handle(_ userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
     if userActivity.activityType == "HandWashIntent"{
         WKExtension.shared().rootInterfaceController?.pushController(withName: "Wash", context: nil)
     }
}
```

but without success. So, how do I check if my app is launched by a Siri shortcut on WatchOS?

Answer (score 0):

Check this method on AppDelegate class. The `launchOptions` dictionary indicating the reason the app was launched. From `LaunchOptionsKey` you will get the information.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won’t do. Since I’m developing a Watch only app, there’s no delegate to work around with, as mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: @Mushu did you ever find a way to do this on Apple Watch?

Comment: @CalebBolton Unfortunately, no